# Dialog box freezes and stops responding

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a very specific problem involving a modeless dialog box in my application.

The dialog box freezes and becomes unresponsive to any messages sent to it by other functions in my application. What is interesting is that my debugging tells me that it freezes when the dialog procedure has received just around 5000 messages that it **DID NOT** handle. The only explanation I can think of is that the Windows Message Queue may be full and it is more or less confirmed by the fact that the stream of messages going through the dialog box seem to tone down immensely.

Now - I've never used dialog boxes in conjunction with an ordinary main window before, and so I may be making illegal moves. By this I mean that I update the dialog box's controls (static texts and a list box) directly by sending the specific controls messages using SendMessage or SetWindowText functions.

What I think is weird is, that this technique works perfectly until 5000 messages have passed.

The main loop sends messages to the dialog box via the parent window handle and use of IsDialogMessage function.

Both the Main window and the dialog box still receives messages, but the dialog box freezes.

Is there a way for me to empty the message queue manually or check its current volume to check if that is actually the problem? I use PeekMessage function to retrieve my messages, which according to MSDN should remove a message from the bottom of the Message queue.

Here is how I've implemented My main loop ( I am pretty sure it's completely legal ):

```
while (true)    //while there is a message
{
    //if there was a windows message
    if ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE )  )
    {
        if ( msg.message == WM_QUIT  )  //if the message was WM_QUIT
                return 0;   //Exit the message loop

        if (  !IsDialogMessage( m_StatusHwnd, &msg ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        advanceFrame();
    }
}
```

I really hope one of you have an idea about what is wrong, because this is REALLY hard hard to debug!

The Dialog procedure is implemented like so:  ( Sorry that you have to see my actual code )

First the static dialog procedure redirects the messages to a custom method:

```
BOOL CALLBACK DXCore::statusDlgProc( HWND hwnd,
                                    UINT msg,
                                    WPARAM wParam,
                                    LPARAM lParam )
{

    if ( msg == WM_INITDIALOG )  SetWindowLongPtr( hwnd, DWLP_USER, lParam);
    DXCore * pCore = reinterpret_cast<DXCore*>( GetWindowLongPtr( hwnd, DWLP_USER ) ) ;
    if ( pCore ) return pCore->displayStatusDlgProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );

    //return the message for windows to handle it
    return FALSE;
}
```

Then the actual procedure looks like this:

```
BOOL                DXCore::displayStatusDlgProc( HWND hwnd,
                                        UINT msg,
                                        WPARAM wParam,
                                        LPARAM lParam )
{




HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush( COLORREF( RGB( 255, 0, 0 ) ) ); //red
HPEN blackPen = CreatePen( PS_SOLID, 2, COLORREF( RGB(0,0,0 ) ) );
HDC hdc; PAINTSTRUCT ps;


RECT clientArea; 
GetClientRect( hwnd, &clientArea );
int gizmoRadius= 5;


m_GismoOrigon.x = clientArea.left + 150;
m_GismoOrigon.y = clientArea.top + 460;

//OutputDebugString( "Dillermand\n" );
dlgProcCounter += 1;




switch ( msg )
{


case WM_INITDIALOG:
    m_FPSCount = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_STATIC_FPS );
    if ( !m_FPSCount ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghFPSCount", "DAMN", MB_OK );

    m_CamPosX = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_CAMPOSX );
    if ( !m_CamPosX ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghCamPosX", "DAMN", MB_OK );

    m_CamPosY = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_CAMPOSY );
    if ( !m_CamPosY ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghCamPosY", "DAMN", MB_OK );

    m_CamPosZ = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_CAMPOSZ );
    if ( !m_CamPosZ ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghCamPosZ", "DAMN", MB_OK );

    m_hStatusMessages = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDSTATUS_PROGMSG );
    if ( !m_hStatusMessages ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghStatusMessages", "DAMN", MB_OK );
    else
    {
        SetParent( m_hStatusMessages, hwnd );
    }


    m_RunButton = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDCSTATUS_RUN_BTN );
    if ( !m_RunButton ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghRunButton ", "DAMN", MB_OK );

    m_PauseButton = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDSTATUS_PAUSE_BTN );
    if ( !m_PauseButton ) MessageBox( NULL, "ghPauseButton", "DAMN", MB_OK );

    SetWindowText( m_CamPosX, "0" );
    SetWindowText( m_CamPosY, "0" );
    SetWindowText( m_CamPosZ, "0" );



    return TRUE;

case WM_PAINT:



    hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

        SelectObject( hdc, brush );
        SelectObject( hdc, blackPen );
        Ellipse( hdc, m_GismoOrigon.x - gizmoRadius, m_GismoOrigon.y - gizmoRadius, m_GismoOrigon.x + gizmoRadius, m_GismoOrigon.y + gizmoRadius ) ;

        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );

    return TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:

    return TRUE;

case WM_NOTIFY:

    return TRUE;

case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    return TRUE;


case WM_TIMER:
    return TRUE;



case WM_DESTROY:
    if ( MessageBox( hwnd, "Exit Program?", "Do Not Want!", MB_YESNO ) == IDYES )
    {
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
    }
    else ShowWindow(m_StatusHwnd, true );
    return TRUE;




case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow( m_StatusHwnd );

    return TRUE;


default:

    string s = std::to_string( dlgProcCounter ) + " Unhandled Dlg message: " + std::to_string( msg ) + "\n";
    OutputDebugString( s.c_str( ) );
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}



return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your window proc for the dialog box?

Comment: Also, how long does `advanceFrame()` take to complete? If you change your message loop from `if (PeekMessage(...` to `while (PeekMessage(...` does it make a difference?

Comment: (to explain my above comment - say advanceFrame() takes 1/50th of a second, that means your message loop can process at most 50 messages per second. Easy to see how it could get bogged down doing that)

Comment: Thank you for your input: The AdvanceFrame( ) does not take time right now - because it does nearly nothing ( we are talking 200 - 1000 nanoseconds ) . I don't know how to implement a while ( peekMessage ... ) and still make sure that AdvanceFrame is run. The danger is that if there's no messages only once, the loop will end.

Comment: Literally all you would do is change `if` to `while` and take out the `else`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you for your suggestion. Even when the AdvanceFrame is not run - the dialog frame freezes at 5000 messages approximately . :S

Comment: The point of this setup, is that if there's a message in the queue, these messages will be processed before a call to advanceFrame( ). Also - the windows message queue has a volume of 10000. I would have thought it was supposed to have 50 messages in queue.

Comment: `BOOL DXCore::displayStatusDlgProc...` strange signature of dialog function. It should return `INT_PTR`, no?

Comment: @c-smile It is a very valid point! Although - It makes no difference. The BOOL type might be implemented that way internally, that is. The DLGPROC will not accept returning standard bool types "false" or "true" but will happily return "FALSE" or "TRUE". I HAVE tried changing it to INT_PTR. There's no difference :) :S

Comment: How are you showing the dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dialog procedure is creating two GDI objects, a brush and pen, every time it's called. It never destroys these objects. By default there's a 10,000 per process limit on GDI objects. Once you reach that limit the calls to create the objects will fail. Your code will then try to draw using invalid handle values, making it appear that your window has frozen.

The solution is to only create the objects once when handling the WM_INITDIALOG message. Also always check the return value of the functions you call for errors. If you had checked the return values to CreateSolidBrush and CreatePen you potentially could have figured this out earlier.

Comment: Wow! That's so true. Thank you - also for the debugging advise! I had not even considered that this could be the problem. I am most grateful.